# Prevent Unnecessary Re-rendering of Child Elements

Tags: reactjs, dom, rendering, react-hooks

I am creating a global notifications component in react that provides a `createNotification` handle to its children using `Context`. The notifications are rendered along with `props.children`. Is there anyway to prevent the re-rendering of the `props.children` if they haven't changed?

I have tried using `React.memo` and `useMemo(props.children, [props.children])` to no prevail.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Notifications>
      <OtherComponent/>
    </Notifications/>
  );
}

const Notifications = (props) => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
  const createNotification = (newNotification) => {
    setNotifications([...notifications, ...newNotification]);
  }

  const NotificationElems = notifications.map((notification) => <Notification {...notification}/>);
  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={createNotification}>
      <React.Fragment>
        {NotificationElems}
        {props.children}
      </React.Fragment>
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
};

const OtherComponent = () => {
  console.log('Re-rendered');
  return <button onClick={() => useContext(NotificationContext)(notification)}>foo</button>
}
```

Every time a new `notification` is created, `props.children` is re-rendered even though nothing actually changes within it. It just adds elements along side it. This can be quite expensive if you have a big app and everything re-renders for each `notification` that shows up. If there is no way to prevent this, how can I split it up so I can do this:

```
<div>
  <OtherComponent/>
  <Notifications/>
</div>
```

and share with `OtherComponent` the `createNotification` handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook to create your `createNotification` imperative handler. Otherwise you will create a new function on every render of the `Notifications` component which will lead to all components consuming your context to re-render because you always pass a new handler whenever you add a notification.

Also you likely didn't mean to spread the `newNotification` into the array of notifications.

The next thing you need to do is to provide the [updater callback version](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) of setState inside `setNotifications`. It gets passed the current list of notifications that you can use the append the new one. This makes your callback independent of the current value of the notification state. It is usually an error to update the state based on the current state without using an updater function because react batches multiple updates.

```
const Notifications = props => {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

    // use the useCallback hook to create a memorized handler
    const createNotification = useCallback(
        newNotification =>
            setNotifications(
                // use the callback version of setState
                notifications => [...notifications, newNotification],
            ),
        [],
    );

    const NotificationElems = notifications.map((notification, index) => <Notification key={index} {...notification} />);

    return (
        <NotificationContext.Provider value={createNotification}>
            <React.Fragment>
                {NotificationElems}
                {props.children}
            </React.Fragment>
        </NotificationContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Another issue is that you conditionally call the `useContext` hook which is not allowed. [Hooks must be called unconditionally](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

```
const OtherComponent = () => {
    // unconditiopnally subscribe to context
    const createNotification = useContext(NotificationContext);

    console.log('Re-rendered');

    return <button onClick={() => createNotification({text: 'foo'})}>foo</button>;
};
```

Fully working example:

[image: Edit 31wx7q9y75]

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thank you. I just have one questions though. Isn't using the callback version of `setState` unnecessary as `notifications` is already within the scope of the function?

Comment: @RhinoBomb No. For two reasons: First and most important react may batch multiple calls to `setState`. That means that multiple fast updates may be lost without the callback beause your outer variable holding the state is already stale. See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) for details. The other reason is that you need your callback to be independent of the outer state or you will re-create the handler if you add a notification. This will lead to your components consuming the context will re-render. That is what you want to prevent.